# JavaScript: getElementById() not working (with either table or paragraph that previously access database)

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom, getelementbyid

I'm stuck on a problem where i want to retrieve a html-element for use in javascript. I'm trying to use the function getElementById(), whick did/does work another element (a shopping cart in which items are placed by clicking on a picture), but not for the ones i'm currently working on (a table (or after i gave up on that a paragraph) that holds some information via "data-"-attributes (e.g. data-price) (so that those don't have to be passed/accessed via json etc)).
I always get the error that the variable i'm assigning the gotten Element to is null ("TypeError: datentabelle is null").

This is the full .js-file called "MyJS.js":

```
function addpizza( pizzanummer, pizzaname, preis) {
"use strict";
    var warenkorb = document.getElementById("warenkorb");
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = pizzanummer;
    opt.label = pizzaname;
    //opt.data-datapreis = preis;
    warenkorb.appendChild(opt);
    var para = document.getElementById("paragraphid");
    let bisherpreis = para.textContent;
    let neupreis = parseFloat(bisherpreis) + parseFloat(preis);
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    para.textContent = neupreis.toFixed(2);

    var datentabelle = document.getElementById(0);     !!This is were the assignment is supposed to happen!!
    var aktpreis = datentabelle.data-preis;            !!This is were the error is thrown (when "datentabelle" is first accessed)!!
    //calc();
}


/*
function calc(){
    //no useable body currently
}
*/
```

This is an excerpt of the HTML-elements code/construction

```
        foreach($dbergebnisse as $pizza){
            $aktpizzanummer = $pizza["PizzaNummer"];
            $aktname     = $pizza["PizzaName"];
            $aktpreis    = $pizza["Preis"];
            $aktbilddatei  = $pizza["Bilddatei"];
echo <<< test10
        <p id=$aktpizzanummer data-preis=$aktpreis> idptemp </p>
        <p>$aktname</p>
        <p>$aktpreis €</p>
        <img src=$aktbilddatei alt="margherita" width="80" height="80" onclick="addpizza($aktpizzanummer,'$aktname',$aktpreis)">
test10;
```

and this is the corresponding full .php-file if relevant:

```
<?php   // UTF-8 marker äöüÄÖÜß€
/**
 * Class PageTemplate for the exercises of the EWA lecture
 * Demonstrates use of PHP including class and OO.
 * Implements Zend coding standards.
 * Generate documentation with Doxygen or phpdoc
 * 
 * PHP Version 5
 *
 * @category File
 * @package  Pizzaservice
 * @author   Bernhard Kreling, <b.kreling@fbi.h-da.de> 
 * @author   Ralf Hahn, <ralf.hahn@h-da.de> 
 * @license  http://www.h-da.de  none 
 * @Release  1.2 
 * @link     http://www.fbi.h-da.de 
 */

// to do: change name 'PageTemplate' throughout this file
require_once './Page.php';

/**
 * This is a template for top level classes, which represent 
 * a complete web page and which are called directly by the user.
 * Usually there will only be a single instance of such a class. 
 * The name of the template is supposed
 * to be replaced by the name of the specific HTML page e.g. baker.
 * The order of methods might correspond to the order of thinking 
 * during implementation.

 * @author   Bernhard Kreling, <b.kreling@fbi.h-da.de> 
 * @author   Ralf Hahn, <ralf.hahn@h-da.de> 
 */
class Bestellung extends Page
{

    // to do: declare reference variables for members 
    // representing substructures/blocks

    /**
     * Instantiates members (to be defined above).   
     * Calls the constructor of the parent i.e. page class.
     * So the database connection is established.
     *
     * @return none
     */
    protected function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // to do: instantiate members representing substructures/blocks
    }

    /**
     * Cleans up what ever is needed.   
     * Calls the destructor of the parent i.e. page class.
     * So the database connection is closed.
     *
     * @return none
     */
    protected function __destruct() 
    {
        parent::__destruct();
    }

    /**
     * Fetch all data that is necessary for later output.
     * Data is stored in an easily accessible way e.g. as associative array.
     *
     * @return none
     */
    protected function getViewData()
    {
        // to do: fetch data for this view from the database
        $angebot = array();

        $SQLabfrage = "SELECT * FROM angebot";
        $Recordset = $this->_database  ->query ($SQLabfrage);//$Recordset = $this->_database  ->query ($SQLabfrage);        //wird hier jetzt iwie einfach ein recordset deklariert (ohne klasse usw?)

        if (!$Recordset)
            throw new Exception("Query failed: ".$Connection->error);

        //return $Recordset;


        $counter = 0;
        $pizza = array();                   //konnte man iwie net drinnen definieren??
        while ($record = $Recordset->fetch_assoc()){
            $pizza["PizzaNummer"] = $record["PizzaNummer"];
            $pizza["PizzaName"]   = $record["PizzaName"];
            $pizza["Preis"]       = $record["Preis"];
            $pizza["Bilddatei"]   = $record["Bilddatei"];
            //$angebot[0] = $pizza;
            array_push($angebot, $pizza);
        }

        return $angebot;
    }






    /**
     * First the necessary data is fetched and then the HTML is 
     * assembled for output. i.e. the header is generated, the content
     * of the page ("view") is inserted and -if avaialable- the content of 
     * all views contained is generated.
     * Finally the footer is added.
     *
     * @return none
     */
    protected function generateView()                   //warum geht $record (in schleife) benutzen hier nicht, aber in getviewdata schon??
    {

        $dbergebnisse = $this->getViewData();
        //$record = $this->$Recordset;
        //$aktnummer = $record["PizzaNummer"];
        $this->generatePageHeader('Bestellung');
        // to do: call generateView() for all members
            //<form action="https://echo.fbi.h-da.de/" method="POST">   
            //<form action="http://127.0.0.1/pizzaservice/Kundeerbend.php" method="POST">   //original

        //$_SESSION["testwert"] = "bla";
        //<form action="http://127.0.0.1/pizzaservice/Kundeerbend.php" method="POST">   
    echo <<< test1
        <body>

        <form action="http://127.0.0.1/pizzaservice/ewa/Kundeerbend.php" method="POST">     

        <h2> Bestellung</h2>
        <h2> Speisekarte</h2>
test1;

        foreach($dbergebnisse as $pizza){
            $aktpizzanummer = $pizza["PizzaNummer"];
            $aktname      = $pizza["PizzaName"];
            $aktpreis     = $pizza["Preis"];
            $aktbilddatei  = $pizza["Bilddatei"];
echo <<< test10
        <p id=$aktpizzanummer data-preis=$aktpreis> idptemp </p>
        <p>$aktname</p>
        <p>$aktpreis €</p>
        <img src=$aktbilddatei alt="margherita" width="80" height="80" onclick="addpizza($aktpizzanummer,'$aktname',$aktpreis)">
test10;

        }

/*      
        echo <<< test1
        <body>
    <form action="http://127.0.0.1/pizzaservice/Kundeerbend.php" method="POST">
    <h2> Bestellung</h2>
    <h2> Speisekarte</h2>
*/  
/*

    <!-- Pizzen aus Datenbank -->
    <img src="ewabild.jpg" alt="margherita" width="80" height="80">
    <p>Margherita</p>
    <p>4.00€</p>
    <img src="ewabild.jpg" alt="salami" width="80" height="80">
    <p>Salami</p>
    <p>4.50€</p>
    <img src="ewabild.jpg" alt="hawaii" width="80" height="80">
    <p>Hawaii</p>
    <p>5.50€</p>
*/  
        $angebotsgroesse = count($dbergebnisse);            //kein code in ausgabe!! (also nicht nach echo)
echo <<< test1
    <h2>Warenkorb</h2>


    <select name="top[]" id= "warenkorb" size=" $angebotsgroesse " multiple>
test1;

foreach($dbergebnisse as $pizza){
            $aktpizzanummer = $pizza["PizzaNummer"];
            $aktname      = $pizza["PizzaName"];
            $aktpreis     = $pizza["Preis"];
            $aktbilddatei  = $pizza["Bilddatei"];

echo <<< test1
            <option value = "$aktpizzanummer"> $aktname </option>
test1;
}
echo "</select>";













/*
echo <<< test2
<table name = "blatabelle" id="infoetc" size=" $angebotsgroesse " multiple>
<tr>
    <td>"bla</td>
</tr>
test2;


foreach($dbergebnisse as $pizza){
            $aktpizzanummer = $pizza["PizzaNummer"];
            $aktname      = $pizza["PizzaName"];
            $aktpreis     = $pizza["Preis"];
            $aktbilddatei  = $pizza["Bilddatei"];

echo <<< test1
            <tr id = "$aktpizzanummer">
                <td data-name>$aktname</td>
                <td data-preis>$aktpreis</td>
            </tr>
test1;
}

echo "</table>";
*/



echo <<< test1
    <p id="paragraphid">0</p>
    <input type="hidden" name="gesamtpreis" value="14.50" />
    <p><label>
        <input type="text" name="Zuname" placeholder="Ihr Nachname"/>
        </label></p>
    <p><label>
        <input type="text" name="kundenadresse" placeholder="Ihre Adresse"/>
        </label></p>
    <input type="reset" name="Alle löschen" value="Alle Löschen" />
    <input type="button" name="Auswahl löschen" value="Auswahl Löschen" />
    <input type="submit" name="bestellen" value="Bestellen"  />
    </form>
    <script type ="text/javascript" src="MyJS.js"></script>
</body>
test1;
        // to do: output view of this page
        $this->generatePageFooter();
    }

    /**
     * Processes the data that comes via GET or POST i.e. CGI.
     * If this page is supposed to do something with submitted
     * data do it here. 
     * If the page contains blocks, delegate processing of the 
     * respective subsets of data to them.
     *
     * @return none 
     */
    protected function processReceivedData() 
    {
        parent::processReceivedData();
        // to do: call processReceivedData() for all members

    }

    /**
     * This main-function has the only purpose to create an instance 
     * of the class and to get all the things going.
     * I.e. the operations of the class are called to produce
     * the output of the HTML-file.
     * The name "main" is no keyword for php. It is just used to
     * indicate that function as the central starting point.
     * To make it simpler this is a static function. That is you can simply
     * call it without first creating an instance of the class.
     *
     * @return none 
     */    
    public static function main() 
    {
        //session_start();
        try {
            $page = new Bestellung();
            $page->processReceivedData();

            $page->generateView();
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            header("Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}

// This call is starting the creation of the page. 
// That is input is processed and output is created.
Bestellung::main();

// Zend standard does not like closing php-tag!
// PHP doesn't require the closing tag (it is assumed when the file ends). 
// Not specifying the closing ? >  helps to prevent accidents 
// like additional whitespace which will cause session 
// initialization to fail ("headers already sent"). 
//? >
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Yes it's very rudimentary and should probably be changed long-term, but should be unique for now. (In the database pizzas are stored and each is assigned an automatically incremented number starting with zero that i also use as an id in HTML, so currently i'm accessing the first entry/the output of the first entry in HTML).

Comment: Also it didnt work either when i manually assigned a unique id to a table and wanted to access that (the data-elements were still assgined from the database).

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to `data-preis` via [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset),

Cou your code will be smth like:

```
function addPizza() {
     /* Your logic */
    var datentabelle = document.getElementById(0); 
    var aktpreis = datentabelle.dataset.preis;    

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but doesn't seem to change anything/still get the same error). (My code might have well failed later for not using ".dataset", so thanks a lot for the comment, but to me it seems like i'm still stuck at just trying to assign anything to datentabelle(, so couldn't make that error yet).)(Since the error says "TypeError: datentabelle is null".)

Comment: As far as I can remember `id` **must** be a string, you already tried it?

Comment: Tried it, but didn't seem to change anything.
Changed "var datentabelle = document.getElementById(0);" to "var datentabelle = document.getElementById("0");" and "<p id= $aktpizzanummer data-preis=$aktpreis> idptemp </p>" to "<p id= (strval($aktpizzanummer)) data-preis=$aktpreis> idptemp </p>".